# Yii what is the use for formatRaw?

Tags: php, function, class, yii, format

My question is regarding CFormatter function:

```
/**
 * Formats the value as is without any formatting.
 * This method simply returns back the parameter without any format.
 * @param mixed $value the value to be formatted
 * @return string the formatted result
 */
public function formatRaw($value)
{
    return $value;
}
```

Why would someone need this? It returns the exact given value.

I only guess it can be used as a placeholder. Could you please give me an example where it can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used where the default format is 'text' e.g in CGridView or CDetailView. If the `type` was not set to raw in the following CGridView code, the `value` would be escaped and printed as `<a>Link</a><img scr='test'/>` instead of html.

```
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'header'=>'This link and picture only show when the format is html or raw',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>"<a>Link</a><img scr='test'/>",
    )
```

**EDIT**

The [CHtmlPurifier API page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtmlPurifier) gives a reason why `raw` would be preferred over `html`

> Note: since HTML Purifier is a big package, its performance is not very good. You should consider either caching the purification result or purifying the user input before saving to database.

Comment: "*This link and picture are only show when the format is raw*" is false. It will also display when the format is `:html`.